# How to init and malloc array to pointer on C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

It looks like I have a memory leak when I try to initializ an array of pointers. This my code:

```
void initLabelTable(){
    register int i;
    hashNode** hp;
    labelHashTable = (hashNode**) malloc(HASHSIZE*sizeof(hashNode*));
    hp = labelHashTable;
    for(i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++) {
        *(hp+i) = NULL;
    }
}
```

#### Update:

I have this code:

```
c = fgetc(fp);

printf("%c",c);
line[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH] = '\0';

initLabelTable();
c = fgetc(fp);
```

I get a segmentation fault on last row although the first getc succeeds.
When I watch `fp` I see a different address. Any ideas?

Comment: Off topic: have you considered changing this to `calloc(HASHSIZE, sizeof(hashNode*))`?  This will initialize the memory to zero.  On some platforms (I know OpenBSD does this) it will also check for integer overflow when multiplying the sizes.

Comment: Where is labelHashTable declared?  Is it a file-scope (global) variable?

Comment: ' *(hp+i) ' This is indecent.

Answer (score 1):

No, this function by itself doesn't leak any memory. It allocates memory for `labelHashTable`, which, according to it's name, is what it's supposed to do.

Make sure that the memory pointed to by `labelHashTable` is freed once you're finished using it, else you will have a memory leak there. Also don't call `initLabelTable()` repeatedly without freeing `labelHashTable` before each subsequent call.